# Find a hypergraph such that $|e|$ even, $|e\cap f|$ odd, and $|E|>|V|$

Tags: combinatorics, hypergraphs

Here is a problem I have been working on (it comes from the standard "odd-town" problem. The idea is to show that the analogy for "even-town" doesn't work).

> Find a hypergraph such that the edges have even size, the intersection of any two edges has odd size, and there are strictly more edges then vertices.

Some things to note: any two edges must intersect, since empty intersection is even.

In any intersecting linear space, $|E|=|V|$. Since our graph is intersecting, it must NOT be a linear space. That is, at least two vertices are not connected by any edge.

The Fisher inequality says that if the intersection of any two edges is $\lambda>0$, then $|E|\le |V|$. Thus, there must be more than one possible "intersection size."

From trying cases, I believe you need at least five vertices to find such a hypergraph. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can prove all edges have at least $4$ vertices.

Comment: I can't actually, sorry about that.

Comment: There is no counter if the ground set has size less than $9$.

Comment: There is no counter of size $9$ either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out no such counterexample can exist.

Look at theorem $2$ in [this pdf](http://math.mit.edu/~fox/MAT307-lecture15.pdf)